# How to ignore hooks?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have following model:

```
sequelize.define("User", {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(60),
        allowNull: false
    },
    role: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(32),
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 'user',
    }
},{

    instanceMethods: {
        verifyPassword: function(password,cb) {
            crypt.compare(password,this.password,cb);
        },
    },

    hooks: {
        beforeUpdate: hashPassword,
        beforeCreate: hashPassword,
    }

});
```

I would like to create it like this while ignoring beforeUpdate/Create hooks:

`User.create({ email: 'admin@render.ly', role: 'admin', password: '############' },['email','password','role']).done(function(err,admin){ ... })`

How?

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this:

```
return User.findOrCreate({
    where: {email: "admin@render.ly"},
    defaults: {
        email: "admin@render.ly",
        role: "admin",
        password: "pyxBOZUNYNZCegyhthKCR9hWpgYO"
    },
    hooks: false //this will ignore hooks
})
```

Comment: Same here, didn't work for me either (5.13.1) @MarkJackson

Comment: 'hooks:false' written inside queries (create, update etc.) works as expected, hooks will not be initiated for them.

Answer (score 0):

I am beginning to use Sequelize myself and this might be a late answer but instead of declaring your hooks in your Model definition, did you try to use the `.hook()` method or the direct method as described in the docs http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/hooks, based on a condition which is linked to your defined roles?
What did you end up using?